# How to send image dimension from javascript to back-end (express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

On the front-end I'm using npm package `cropperjs` to crop image on the fly

```
    const croppedCanvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas();
    const boxCanvas = getBoxCanvas(croppedCanvas);
    const croppedImage = document.createElement('img');

     croppedImage.src = boxCanvas.toDataURL();
     croppedImage.onload = function () {
              console.log(this.width, this.height);     
      }
```

I wanna be able to grab a hold of this image dimension(width and height) on express to save the image with new width and height using npm package `gm` like so:

```
router.post("/upload", (req, res) => {    
gm("public/images/" + sampleFile.name)
          // use the '!' flag to ignore aspect ratio
          .resize(width, height, '!')
          .noProfile()
          .write("public/images/edited/" + sampleFile.name, function (err) {
            if (!err) console.log('done');
          });
});
```

So how could be able to send the new widht and height of the image to express route from the front-end? any help I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be easily solved with a little browser JS.
In the following code, you will send an HTTP POST request from your browser to a path on your server:

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('post', 'http://mycoolsite.com/sendimagemeta/');
xhr.send('w=' + this.width + '&h=' + this.height);
```

Now that we have sent the server the data, we need to get that data from the server-side.

```
app.use(express.urlencoded()) // Urlencoded to parse the request body

router.post('/sendimagemeta', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body) // => Would be a JSON like this:
  /*
      {
          "w": 123,
          "h": 123 // The image's width and height
      }
  */
  // Now you can do your parsing with the JSON, you might need to convert it to an object or string, etc
  // { ... }
  // After it's parsed, we need to end the response.
  res.end('Thank you.')
}
```

Comment: thanks man it was obvious that I was missing the part of `XMLHttpRequest`..

Comment: @AbdallaAbdalmunim I do this a lot, one time I had a page that had to read a file so I set up something like this where it sends a blank `GET` request saying **Hey! Give me /somesuperimportantfile.json!** so I'm used to this kind of stuff. :p